# Command object passing any values in asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table with 1 record and I made a stored procedure for it to use in my button click, but it's letting me pass any values and when I test it in sql, it works as expected. Just wondering if any of you can point out the bug in my code.

```cs
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataReader dr = default(SqlDataReader);
    SqlCommand cmd = default(SqlCommand);
    string userName = txtUserName.Text;
    string password = txtPassword.Text;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("adminAuthentication", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", userName); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password); 

        conn.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Successfull login!";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Wrong user/password";
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROC adminAuthentication
(
    @UserName varchar(15),
    @Password varchar(25)
)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM AdminLogin 
    WHERE UserName = @UserName AND Pwd = @Password
END
```

Comment: plain-text passwords, nice o_O

Comment: *"it's letting me pass any values [...] it works as expected"* - So... What's the problem?

Comment: It works on sql. If i punch in incorrect data, nothing gets returned. Yet on on my win form it passes anything, it's as if the command object isn't working

Comment: @guyboris: Oh, you mean it "passes" as in all inputs result in a successful login?  Time to do some debugging then.  At runtime, what are the values of `username` and `password`?  What is the value of the `dr.HasRows` property?  What rows are present in the `DataReader` at that time?

Comment: This stored procedure will always return a row, since it is a COUNT. It will return 0 if the username and password don't match and it will return 1 if they match. In either case you get back a row and dr.HasRows will be true

Comment: That was my problem! I removed COUNT and it's now working. Thank you so much!